# Как выбрать все записи после текущей

Tags: mysql

Не могу понять хотя задача кажеться простой есть таблица

```
id|date      |text  |uri
1 |23/09/1999|blabla|uri1
2 |23/06/1999|blabla|rtgrt
3 |23/06/2000|blabla|rtrt
5 |12/06/2010|blabla|rtrt
6 |12/01/1990|blabla|rtrt
```

как одним запросом зная урл страницы выбрать 2 следующих записи отсортированные по дате.

Comment: Я бы дату записывал в UNIX-формате, тогда бы проблем не возникало. В вашем же случае существует трудность в сортировке. UNIX-дату всегда можно преобразовать с помощью php.

Comment: думаю формат тут не причем,попробуйте построит запись?

Comment: @ukroficer Это сортировка по убыванию:

    SELECT * FROM  `table` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 2;
По возрастанию:

    SELECT * FROM  `table` ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 2;
Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: и?Я думаю это очевидно?

Comment: то как построить запрос вы знаете?

Answer (score 1):

решил проблему вот так

SELECT id, `date` FROM `table`  WHERE `date` > (SELECT `date` FROM `table` WHERE uri='uri1'  )  ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 2

Comment: @ukroficer простите, видимо я не понял сути вашей проблемы. :)
Вы немного вопрос неточно задали, как мне показалось. :)